# How to get pointers initialized back from the .txt file

Tags: c++

I'm using pointers of class objects.Then i write in reservation file data.And if i read from .txt file i cannot read poiners.What's the good  way to initialize pointers
Should i use additional variables(userLogin,roomId) and then match  additional variables with variables of objects and get address from them?

```
class Guest
{
    public:
    string login;
    string password;
    string name;
};
class Room
{
    public:
    int id;
    string type;
};
class Reservation
{
    public:
    string checkOut;
    string checkIn;
    Room* room;
    Guest* user;
    string userLOgin;
    int roomId;
};
class Manage
{
    void MakeResrvation(Guest* user,Room* room,bool appendToFile)
    {
        string checkIn,checkOut;
        ofstream writer(ReservationPath, appendToFile ? ios::app : ios::out);
        if (writer.is_open()) {
            writer<<room->id<<Delimiter<<user->login<<Delimiter<<checkIn<<Delimiter<<checkOut<<Delimiter;
            writer<<endl;
        } 
    }
    vector<Reservation*> LoadFromFile() {
    ifstream reader(ReservationPath);
    vector<Reservation*> reservations;
    if (reader.is_open()) {
        string line;
        while (getline(reader, line))
        {
            vector<string> items = Split(line, Delimiter);
            Reservation* reservation = new Reservation;
            reservation->roomId=stoi(items.at(0));
            reservation->userLOgin=items.at(1);
            reservation->checkIn=items.at(2);
            reservation->checkOut=items.at(3);
            reservations.push_back(reservation);
        }
        reader.close();
    }
    return reservations;
};
```

I expect to get pointer in the most optimized way.

Comment: ***i read from .txt file i cannot read poiners*** That is correct. You should not be able to do that. Never save a pointer to a file. It's not valid to restore.

Comment: You may want to read about this: https://isocpp.org/wiki/faq/serialization#serialize-overview

Comment: You don't store pointers, what you are storing is the value of the instance variable of the object. Since that's all that's relevant. As @drescherjm mentioned, look into serialisation. You can store binary data in a file, then read the data and instantiate a new object using the values stored earlier.

Comment: why are you using pointers? you dont need to

Answer (score 1):

#### Why it doesn't make sense to read and write pointers to files ?

It makes no sense to read a pointer from a file. A pointer is an address within the memory space.  When you create your reservation, the pointer points to an address where a valid object (e.g. a `Room` or a `Guest`) is supposed to be stored:

```
void test() 
{
   Room r{12,"big room"}; 
   Guest g{"XYZ","...","Mr XY, Z"}; 
   manager.MakeReservation(&g, &r, true);   
}    // r and g are destroyed here
```

When you later read the pointer, you are not sure that a valid object is still at the place where it was before.  In the example above, the pointers  pointed to local objects, and these have been destroyed in the meantime.

Worse, if you would read the file from another process (e.g., when running your program again the next day) the address space might be completely different, and the object you where hoping pointing to might never have existed there.

#### How to solve your problem ?

In a `Reservation` you have the key information to uniquely identify the objects you are looking for:  `roomId` should uniquely identify a `Room`, and `userLOgin` should uniquely identify a `Guest` (at least I'll assume so hereafter), and regardless of the place where they are stored.

So what you need to do is to store somewhere *repositories* of rooms and guests: when you read your reservation, you need to search in the repository the corresponding objects, and set the pointers accordingly.  OF course, you need to adapt your code: either pass the repositories as argument to the function that needs them,  or store them as members of `Manage`.

Another alternative, could be when you save the object, also save the data of the pointed objects.  When you then read the data, you'd have to create not only the reservation, but also the "embedded" objects, and initialise the pointers accordingly.  This is a little bit more complex, but you can google for *serialization* to know more about this process.

#### Other improvements

Attention when you write data, in case the strings you are writing contain the delimiter:  this could lead to nasty bugs when reading the file.

I'd suggest also to use in reservation either a `roomId` and always find the room in the repository when it's needed, or a pointer to `Room`, knowing that the id can be found there.  Having redundant information in `Reservation` could lead weird things to happen such as pointing to an object with a different id than expected.

Now if you're managing your repositories in form of  `vector<Reservation*>`, `vector<Room*>`, and `vector<Guest*>`,  you may be interested in using `vector<shared_ptr<Reservation>>`, `vector<shared_ptr<Room>>`, and `vector<shared_ptr<Guest>>`, since [`shared_ptr`](https://en.cppreference.com/w/cpp/memory/shared_ptr) facilitates memory management.

Finally, for your repositories, you may consider using [`std::map`](https://en.cppreference.com/w/cpp/container/map) instead of `std::vector`,  where the key to the map would be the unique identifier.